# Quais os comandos de um Superusuario?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de saber quais são os Direitos que um Superusuario possuí dentro de um banco de dados.

- Ele pode fazer quais alterações?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privilégio  Descrição
ALL [PRIVILEGES]    Todos os privilégios exceto GRANT OPTION

- ALTER    Permite executar ALTER TABLE
- CREATE   Permite executar CREATE TABLE
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES  Permite executar CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
- DELETE   Permite executar DELETE**texto em negrito**
- DROP Permite executar DROP TABLE
- EXECUTE  Permite executar stored procedures (MySQL 5.0)
- FILE Permite executar SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE e LOAD DATA INFILE
- INDEX    Permite executar CREATE INDEX e DROP INDEX
- INSERT   Permite executar INSERT
- LOCK TABLES  Permite executar LOCK TABLES em tabelas que você tenha o privilégio SELECT
- PROCESS  Permite executar SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
- REFERENCES   Ainda não está implementado
- RELOAD   Permite executar FLUSH
- REPLICATION CLIENT   Permite ao usuário obter a localização do Master ou Slave
- REPLICATION SLAVE    Necessário para a replicação Slave (leitura dos eventos do log binário do Master)
- SELECT   Permite executar SELECT
- SHOW DATABASES   exibe todos os bancos de dados
- SHUTDOWN Permite executar mysqladmin shutdown
- SUPER    Permite executar CHANGE MASTER, KILL , PURGE MASTER LOGS e SET GLOBAL. Permite conectar-se ao servidor uma vez, mesmo que o max_connections tenha sido atingido
- UPDATE   Permite executar UPDATE
- USAGE    Sinônimo para "no privileges''
- GRANT OPTION Permite ao usuário repassar os seus privilégios